# XEmacs won't read RCS data but my emacs will

Tags: emacs, xemacs, rcs

Normally, I use RCS in cygwin emacs (version 23.3.1 from 2011) and the status bar shows

```
-UU-:----F1
```

and allows me to check-in and check out files. I just downloaded the latest native XEmacs for Windows (21.4.22 from jan 2009) and noticed that my current RCS data isn't triggering any RCS mode in it. The status shown is

```
Raw-----XEmacs: filename.sh
```

. Everything is fine when I open it back in cygwin emacs.

During installation, I noticed only "VC-RCS" as an RCS option, but not the old standard RCS. I take it either it never worked on xemacs, or they've made a change to xemacs alone that I was totally unaware of, since I haven't used it in years.

How can one get plain old RCS support in xemacs?